# How to find an equation for all points (x,y)(x,y) for which f(x,y)f(x,y) has a maximum rate of change in a direction parallel to a given vector vv?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

Find an equation for all the points $(x,y)$ for which the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2−3x−y$
has a maximum rate of change in a direction parallel to the vector $u = (1, 1)$

And here is my attempt to solve it:

- we take the partial derivatives:
  $$ \dfrac {\partial}{\partial x} = 2x-3$$
  $$  \dfrac {\partial}{\partial y} = 2y-1 $$
- now we find the unit vector $\dfrac {\left|\vec{v} \right|} {\left|v \right|}$ $= \dfrac {1} {\sqrt 2}$
- now use the formula that says: $$D_uf(a,b) = f_u′ (a,b) = u·\nabla f(a,b) = u·(f_x(a,b),f_y(a,b))$$
- Hence the equation is  $$\dfrac {2x+2y-4}{\sqrt 2} = \sqrt 2 \{x+y-2\}$$
  which is wrong according to my professor. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: To typeset the character $\partial$ use the command `\partial`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction of maximum rate of change parallel to the gradient vector, which in this case is $\vec\nabla f= (2x-3,2y-1).$ So we need this to be proportional to $(1,1).$ This just means that $2x-3 = 2y-1$ which gives $y = x-1.$ So the solutions are all the points on this line.

Comment: i sent a PM to my teacher and he said the following : Your equation/answer can be rewritten as 0x + 0y = 0 which is trivially true for ALL points (x,y) in R^2, so, no - this is not the answer. The problem requires that grad f is parallel to (1,1), which can be written as 
grad f = k(1,1). Eliminate k and you should get the linear eq. y = x - 1.  how do i eliminate k

Comment: @Reddevil Write out the two equations and it ought to become obvious.

Comment: @Reddevil It's an equation for each component. $\nabla f = (k,k)$ means $2x-3 = k$ and $2y-1 = k.$   So eliminate $k$ from those two equations and you get the answer. This is what I meant when I said the vector being proportional to $(1,1)$ means its components are equal.

Answer (score 1):

See directional derivative, this question is fairly routine.

$$\nabla_{\mathbf v} f(x,y) = \nabla f(x,y) \cdot \mathbf v$$ gives the rate of change in direction $\mathbf v$ and is itself a map from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$. The maximum is a critical point of the total derivative of the directional derivative above, or boundary point.

$$ \nabla_{\mathbf v} f(x,y) = \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} v_x + \frac{\partial f(x,y) }{\partial y} v_y = (2x-3)v_x+(2y-1)v_y=2x+2y-4$$

Seems there is a min at negative infinity. Intuitively it seems $f(x,y)$ is a infinite parabola or extruded parabola, and has no maximum rate of change in direction $(1,1)$